# error: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql, nodemon

How to fix this error nodemon app crashed?I'm using postgres sql as database and not mongodb.
How can I fix this error?

error: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

```
                                                                                                 ^

error: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (C:\Users\HP\Downloads\8.3+Travel+Tracker\8.3 Travel Tracker\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:287:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (C:\Users\HP\Downloads\8.3+Travel+Tracker\8.3 Travel Tracker\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\HP\Downloads\8.3+Travel+Tracker\8.3 Travel Tracker\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP\Downloads\8.3+Travel+Tracker\8.3 Travel Tracker\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12)
    at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:510:3)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:390:5)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
  length: 104,
  severity: 'FATAL',
  code: '28P01',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'auth.c',
  line: '326',
  routine: 'auth_failed'
}

Node.js v20.11.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: It seems you have not correctly entered the password. You should also provide the file where you try to connect to the database. Not possible to make out anything with only the error message 'wrong password'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not defined a password for the postgres user, you must define a password. Just remember that the postgres user is a user with superuser privilege. Therefore, it is not recommended to use it as an application user. You can define a password for the user or change the existing password as follows.
First, log into the database server.

```
sudo su - postgres
psql
```

Change the user's password.

```
alter user postgres with password 'password'
```

Comment: If it solved your problem, you can mark that it resulted with the advice I gave. Enjoy your work